# How to get table column data when a button is clicked

Tags: php, html

Assume that I have a directory page that is generated by PHP. Each row data is from the database.

```
    echo "<form action=\"reservation.php\" method=\"post\">";   
for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) { 
 $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); 

    if ( stripslashes($row['gymid']) == !0) {  
        echo  "<tr>". PHP_EOL; 
        echo  "<td>".stripslashes($i+1)."</td>". PHP_EOL; 
        echo  "<td align=\"center\">".stripslashes($row['gymname'])."</td>". PHP_EOL;    
        echo  "<td>".stripslashes($row['address'])."</td>". PHP_EOL; 
        echo  "<td align=\"center\">".stripslashes($row['location'])."</td>". PHP_EOL;       
        echo  "<td align=\"center\">".stripslashes($row['operatinghours'])."</td>". PHP_EOL;
        echo  "<td align=\"center\"><input type= \"submit\" id =\"gym".stripslashes($row['gymid'])."\" value=\"BOOK NOW\" class=\"bookbutton\" onClick=\"reply_click(this.id)\"</td>". PHP_EOL; 
        //echo "<td align=\"center\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"gyminfo\" class=\"bookbutton\" value=\"".stripslashes($row['gymid'])."\" >BOOK NOW! </td>". PHP_EOL;
        echo  "</tr>". PHP_EOL; 

    }     

} 
  echo "</form>";
```

So i have a "BOOK NOW" button for each row with unique id (gymxxxx). Upon clicking that button, the page will be redirect to reservation.php where there are a few dropdown boxes with gymname, location, timeslot and so on.
The following shows the dropdown box for gymname:

```
<label>Gym Name: </label>
<form id="gymInfoForm" method = "post" action = "reservation.php">
        <select name="gymSelect"onchange="if (this.selectedIndex) formSubmit();">
        <?php 
            $data = $_POST['gymSelect'];        
            echo "Data = " . $data;

            $query = "SELECT * FROM gymname";
            $result = $db->query($query);
            $resultNum = $result->num_rows;
            echo '<option value="NULL" >Please choose a gym</option>';
            for($i = 0; $i < $resultNum; $i++)
            {
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                if($data == $row['gymname'])
                {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['gymname'] . '" selected>' . $row['gymname'] . '</option>'.PHP_EOL;
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['gymname'] . '" >' . $row['gymname'] . '</option>'.PHP_EOL;
                }
            }   
        ?>
        </select>
</div>

    <div style="margin-bottom:10px">
```

My question is, how can i post the data (gymname and location) linked to the "BOOK NOW" button to the reservation.php such that the option for "gymname" and "location" will be preselected?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

U can do `<form>` tag for each row or use JS witch map your data and send to the server.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have any 'names' for your inputs:

put:

```
name='bookNow'
```

in the book now button input tag.

Then put

```
name='gymName'
```

in your pre-populated gym name input tag.

Then you can get the values with php:

```
if(isset($_POST['bookNow'])){
    $gymName = $_POST['gymName'];
}
```